# Multiple date filter Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter

I am trying to filter an `ImageCollection` by multiple time intervals (rain seasons) that change from year to year. Hence, I can't just use the `ee.Filter.calendarRange`.

I tried to merge the dates together and filter the collection but it does not work. What do I have to do?

```js
var ROI = /* color: #0b4a8b */ee.Geometry.Polygon([
      [36.5048217773437, 0.560293804172086],
      [37.9302978515625, 0.560293804172086],
      [37.9302978515625, 1.875580463973453],
      [36.5048217773437, 1.875580463973453]
  ]);
    Map.centerObject(ROI,8);  

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterBounds(ROI);

var longRain2016 = s2.filterDate('2016-04-01','2016-05-31');
var shortRain2016 = s2.filterDate('2016-11-15','2016-12-31');
var longRain2017 = s2.filterDate('2017-04-01','2017-05-31');
var shortRain2017 = s2.filterDate('2017-10-01','2017-12-31');
var longRain2018 = s2.filterDate('2018-03-01','2018-05-31');
var dateFilter = ee.ImageCollection(longRain2016.merge(shortRain2016).merge(longRain2017).merge(shortRain2017).merge(longRain2018));

var s2dateFilter = s2.filter(dateFilter);


var count = s2dateFilter.size();
print('Number of filtered images in the region of interest: ', count);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Your Code

These lines don't seem to work out:

```js
var dateFilter = ee.ImageCollection(longRain2016.merge(shortRain2016).merge(longRain2017).merge(shortRain2017).merge(longRain2018));

var s2dateFilter = s2.filter(dateFilter);
```

You are trying to construct another `ee.ImageCollection` passing existing `ImageCollection`s to it. [According to the API](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagecollection), this won't work.

I also think that it is not necessary to achieve what you want because `ee.ImageCollection.merge` [returns an `ImageCollection` anyway](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagecollectionmerge).

This should work:

```js
var allSeasons = longRain2016.merge(shortRain2016).merge(longRain2017).merge(shortRain2017).merge(longRain2018);
```

Now, since you already should have a merged `ImageCollection` of all the seasons in `allSeasons`, you don't need the second step. (Actually this wouldn't work because your `dateFilter` object is not a [`Filter`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eefilter) and [`filter()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagecollectionfilter) only accepts a `Filter`.)

You can simply proceed with `var count = allSeasons.size();`

#### Alternative way ("The Multiple-Filter-Method")

You could first create the `Filter`s and then [`Filter.or()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eefilteror)-join them together. Next you could apply this joint `Filter` to the `ImageCollection`:

```js
//Create Filters
var longRain2016Filter = ee.Filter.date('2016-04-01','2016-05-31');
var shortRain2016Filter = ee.Filter.date('2016-11-15','2016-12-31');
var longRain2017Filter = ee.Filter.date('2017-04-01','2016-05-31');
var shortRain2017Filter = ee.Filter.date('2017-10-01','2016-12-31');
var longRain2018Filter = ee.Filter.date('2018-03-01','2018-05-31');

var allSeasonsFilter = ee.Filter.or(longRain2016Filter, shortRain2016Filter, longRain2017Filter, shortRain2017Filter, longRain2018Filter); // Create joint Filter

var allSeasons = s2.filter(allSeasonsFilter); //apply Filter to ImageCollection
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That alternative way seems to be a lot smoother.